# Why do my under-cabinet lights flash when two sets are plugged into the transformer?

Tags: lighting

I just installed two 24" IKEA OMLOPP lighting bars under my kitchen cupboards.  When I plug either one into the transformer individually they work fine.  When I plug both of the lights into the transformer the lights start flashing off and on.

Comment: In the product reviews on the IKEA site, they mention that the included transformer, despite having 3 plugs, can only provide enough power for one 24" light strip.  Multiple 24" bars induces a strobe effect.  You will need one of the bigger transformers for that line, or to chain multiple transformers together, as per IKEA.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  Back to IKEA we go.  When we went to IKEA the Associate and her supervisor told us we only needed one 10 WATT transformer for the two 24" bars :(.  Thanks again.

Comment: @ChrisM., please provide a proper answer below. You might link to the reviews you mentioned. Mal, please follow up and accept the answer, or just delete your question. Unresolved questions are ugly.

Comment: And [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) if I'm making no sense. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [IKEA](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/00295728/), the 24" OMLOPP LED bar draws 7.7W of power.  A single 10W transformer will not be enough to provide power to two 24" bars at full brightness, despite the included transformer having slots for multiple bars to be attached.  You will need one of the larger ANSLUTA transformers (seemingly also available in 30W form) or to chain multiple transformers together (also permitted per IKEA).

In fact, it is noted in the reviews that the included 10W transformer, being unable to power two 7.7W bars, will induce a strobing effect if you exceed the rated power.  Presumably, the 10W transformer can provide enough power for multiple smaller bars and is simply the transformer included with all products in that line.